# How to install a portable IE8?

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple versions of Internet Explorer on a machine](https://superuser.com/questions/17670/multiple-versions-of-internet-explorer-on-a-machine)

I have IE9 on my Windows 7, but I want to have IE8 too, because I want to create websites and test them on IE8 too.

How to install a portable IE8 on Windows 7?

Comment: I strongly advise you that supporting older versions of IE only encourage the use of older versions of IE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple versions of Internet Explorer on a machine](http://superuser.com/questions/17670/multiple-versions-of-internet-explorer-on-a-machine). Also see [What's the easiest way to install multiple versions of IE and Firefox on the same (virtual) Windows machine?](http://superuser.com/questions/118069/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-multiple-versions-of-ie-and-firefox-on-the-sam) and lots of similar questions linked to from these two.

Comment: @Ramhound ___Older?___ Are you serious? No IE9 on XP, which is still in widespread use.

Comment: @r.tanner.f - The author is using Windows 7 not Windows XP.  If I wasn't serious I wouldn't have made that comment.

Comment: @Ramhound Webpages are typically made for multiple people to see.

Comment: @r.tanner.f - I understand that.

Answer (score 2):

There is a program called [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) that will allow you to render with different versions of IE on the same machine. It is the only free way I could find, since you can only install one version of IE on a given computer. There are also paid sites that will let you use older versions of IE off their servers.

You could also try to force the browser to display in IE8 emulation mode wih a `META` tage on the page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811801/force-ie9-to-emulate-ie8-possible

Answer (score 1):

There's also a thing called [IECollection](http://utilu.com/IECollection/) which gives you every major version of the software since IE1.0.

But also observe the following note on the website:

> To activate the IE 7.0 or 8.0 render engine in IE 8.0 or 9.0: go to
>   “Tools”, “Developer Tools” (or press F12) and then click on the
>   “Browser Mode” menu item and select for example “Internet Explorer 7”
>   to let the Trident render engine of IE 7.0 render the website.